# tcsh PATH env variable not respected amazon web services

Tags: amazon-ec2, path, command-line-interface

I've got an Amazon EC2 instance with the 64bit Linux AMI. I changed my shell to tcsh and then set up .tcshrc with

```
PATH = ".:/usr/local/lib/play-1.1:$PATH"
```

After a

```
$ source ~/.tcshrc
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/lib/play-1.1:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
```

I can't put anything into my path and have it get picked up for some reason.

I also tried an alias:

```
$ ln -s /usr/local/lib/play-1.1/play /usr/local/bin/play
$ play
play: command not found
```

with the same result, it doesn't get picked up in my path. Am I ignorant of some global config? My experience is with CentOS so this is strange to me.

```
/home/notbrain
notbrain@aws-dev1: echo $PATH
.:/usr/local/lib/play-1.1:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin

/home/notbrain
notbrain@aws-dev1: ls /usr/local/bin
total 8.0K
4.0K drwxr-xr-x  2 root 4.0K Jan 28 05:41 ./
4.0K drwxr-xr-x 13 root 4.0K Jan 11 21:44 ../
   0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   28 Jan 28 05:41 play -> /usr/local/lib/play-1.1/play*

/home/notbrain
notbrain@aws-dev1: play
play: Command not found.

/home/notbrain
notbrain@aws-dev1: sudo play
sudo: play: command not found

/home/notbrain
notbrain@aws-dev1: /usr/local/bin/play
~        _            _
~  _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
~ | '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
~ |  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
~ |_|            |__/
~
~ play! 1.1, http://www.playframework.org
~
~ Usage: play cmd [app_path] [--options]
~
~ with,  new      Create a new application
~        run      Run the application in the current shell
~        help     Show play help
~

/home/notbrain
notbrain@aws-dev1:
```

Thanks,

Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tcsh or csh:

```
set PATH = (. /usr/local/lib/play-1.1 $PATH)
```